# Should I prevent API calls that I know will fail?

Tags: authorization

I'm writing a webapp that serves users with different roles and permissions. One of the features of my application requires an API call to a secured endpoint. If the user doesn't have the correct permissions, the endpoint responds with a 403 Forbidden. In my application, the failed API call has no effect on the behavior on the front end; the error is recovered from as if it never happened except for a failed request in the browser developer tools. Is there any value to preventing the API call in the first place, by inspecting the permissions on the client side and only making the API call if the correct permissions exist?

Comment: The API call already "failed" when it returned a 403 forbidden.  It did exactly what it was supposed to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Validation at the front-end (of inputs, but also of credentials) comes with the cost of having to duplicate the validation logic to both the front and back ends and having to maintain both versions.

Such duplication should only be done when it has a clear benefit that outweighs the costs. Some possible benefits could be

- faster feedback to the user that they entered incorrect data/can't perform that step in the workflow
- reduction in used bandwidth

If bandwidth is not a consideration and the (normal) end-user is not going to notice that the request resulted in a 4xx result, then checking up-front if a request would succeed or fail is only going to produce costs without benefits.

Comment: It might make sense to do _very basic validation_, e.g. there is a non-zero length value, on the front end.  But duplicating the entire back end validation is fraught with maintenance and security nightmares.

Comment: Another reason to do it could be to not overload the core service. You may have lots of proxies that route to the same single core service. In general, as an intermediary, if you know what you are going to get you might as well produce it yourself. It is conceptually close to caching.

Answer (score 2):

There should be one source of truth. The client's truth could be very different from the backend's. Say someone gave you access to a piece of data you didn't have a minute ago. How would your client know about the change? From what it knew a minute ago it would prevent access to a piece of data you *now* have access to. So do not prevent calls.

See the `403` not as a "failing request", though it is not what you expected, see it is a polite way of the server saying "No" - giving you extra information which you haven't had beforehand. And as such it has its own right.